# Git remote does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: git, content-management-system

I'm working on a craft cms application. The repo has 3 remotes:

- origin (bitbucket)
- staging (testing site)
- production (live site)

All of the remotes used to work, but then the production broke for no reason.

Here's how the error looks:

```
fatal: '/srv/users/******/apps/****/repo' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

here's how config file looks on the server

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@bitbucket.org:****/****.git
    fetch = +refs/*:refs/*
    mirror = true
```

don't know what else to check considering that it used to work :-(

**upd.**

turns out the `object` folder slipped into another folder(thanks to my boss) and just moving it back solved the problem!

Comment: Has the `.git` folder been deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the commands which produced the error.

`git ls-remote production` should work.
But your current local configuration does not show any remote "`production`" origin, so you might need to add it back.

I asked the [OP Mikhai Cheburakhtin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12081827/mikhail-cheburakhtin) if, in an interactive remote shell session, he can access `/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/****/repo`, and do a `git log` in it:

> Yes I can, but it throws an error: fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): `.git`

That would explain the error message.

The OP adds:

> I started comparing repo folders and there is `objects` folder that was missing and I find it inside another folder: so just moving this folder back to it's place solved the problem!

Comment: That's config file on the server in repo folder.

Comment: @MikhailCheburakhtin Does `ssh -Tv serverpilot@****.com` work?

Comment: it does work, is there any specific things to look at?
bunch of `debug1` lines, authenticated with password not private key

Comment: @MikhailCheburakhtin Try without the -v: are you able to get a remote interactive session when typing `ssh serverpilot@****.com`

Comment: Yes I am and authenticating with password

Comment: @MikhailCheburakhtin Then which command initially triggered the error? Are you sure it is using the ssh URL defined in your config? Not an HTTPS URL? (for which the wrong credentials might be cached)

Comment: yes, it used to work with this ssh url before, so I think it's legit. I've also tried different variations for this url including HTTPS URL.
Commands like `git push production master` or `git remote show production` resulting an error.

Comment: @MikhailCheburakhtin Are you sure it is a password, not a passphrase? Would  adding the key to the ssh-agent help? (https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.15/user/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent) (only if the private key is passphrase-protected)

Comment: Updated the private key and added to ssh agent, also added new public key to authorized_keys file on server, and now it loads even without passphrase, but still, on command `git remote show production` throws an error:
`fatal: '/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/****/repo' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
`

Comment: @MikhailCheburakhtin Just to be sure, once you have an interactive session with `ssh serverpilot@****.com`, can you access `/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/.../repo`?

Comment: yes, but the path is `/srv/users/serverpilot` and I can access all internal folders

Comment: I've tried to change remote url to: `ssh://serverpilot@****.com/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/****/repo`, `ssh://serverpilot@****.com/~/apps/****/repo`,
`serverpilot@****.com:/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/****/repo`

Comment: @MikhailCheburakhtin Yes that should not change the error. In an interactive remote shell session, can you access `/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/****/repo`, and do a `git log` in it?

Comment: Yes I can, but it throws an error: `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Comment: @MikhailCheburakhtin That is the reason of your error: somehow, that repo is no longer recognized as a Git repo. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @MikhailCheburakhtin Just in case, in your remote interactive session, unser GIT_DIR, as in https://github.com/DonJayamanne/gitHistoryVSCode/issues/233#issuecomment-523362667.

Comment: Ok, but there is no .git files in `srv/users/serverpilot/apps/****-staging/repo` as well, and this remote works. And, if I login on the server with this path and `git log`, it works

So the question is what's missing in the repo folder in production

Comment: Can you post the output of an ls -alrth done in that folder?

Comment: ok, Thanks @VonC, after you walked me through possible problems, I started comparing repo folders and there is `objects` folder that was missing and I find it inside another folder, so just moving this folder back to it's place solved the problem! Fun thing, I started explaining what happened to my boss and it turns out that he messed with the ftp. Thanks again!

Comment: @MikhailCheburakhtin Great! Well done. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

here's how my local config file looks:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "staging"]
    url = ssh://serverpilot@********.com/~/apps/****-staging/repo
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/staging/*
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://********@bitbucket.org/******/****.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "production"]
    url = serverpilot@****.com:/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/****/repo
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/production/*
```

Another question is should the config file on the server have any remotes beside origin?

also, both production and staging folders on the server have repo folder and the config file in the staging folder doesn't have any remotes and works:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = true
```